# Azure DevOps fails to download artifacts from its own repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to publish a project from Azure DevOps to an on-site server.  The project is buildingi fine - and published fine after I set the pipeline to look for the artifacts in the right place.

However, and seemingly in response to nothing, I started getting the following error when the pipeline attempts to download the artifacts
Failed in getBuildAPI with error: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

[image]

From the looks of this it seems that Azure Pipelines can't read it's own artifacts, which seems a little ridiculous.

Usually the root cause of problems like this are deceptive error messages, but I can't for the life of me figure out what could be happening.

What could be causing this problem?

**Update** - the pipeline works approx one out of every ten times I try it, but never two times in a row.

Comment: Can this  [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1396)  help you?

Comment: I don't think so - I'm not running node - and it seems to be having problems downloading something from the build, so I don't think it applies

Comment: Which server are you using? VSTS? Or TFS? In my vsts org, this task running very well-)

Comment: I'm using AzureDevOps/VSTS

Comment: I assume you are using private agent. You can try to access your Azure Devops in your Agent server to check if you have any untrusted warning or error? If yes, you should install your self-signed ssl server certificate into the OS certificate store.

Comment: @SteveFrench, Again, You can try to ignore SSL error set a Variable of name `VSTS_ARM_REST_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS` with value: `true` in the release definition. Or check if there is something in the firewall blocking it

Comment: I have that variable in place actually - it is now failing about half the time.  I don't see how there would be a firewall problem as the problem is seemingly happening all in azure. (before it gets to my server).  it is a strange mystery...

Comment: Could you please enable the variable `system.debug` (set the value to `True`) in your definition and then trigger a new build/release with the Download artifacts task to capture and share the full log here for further troubleshoot?

Comment: I enable debug and now it's not throwing the error anymore...

Comment: I get the same error, with the exact same log as listed above

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: Nope - never did - pursued an alternate path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem was a faulty hardware component on the firewall!  Not actually azure at all.